# Query not working as intended

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a Query which I am trying to execute on a SQLite table. There are records in the table and they map to the selection arguments I pass. Following is my Query and global Strings:

```
 // Table Notifications
    public static final String  notificationfor = "NotificationFor";
    public static final String  datetonotify = "DateToNotify";
    public static final String  isextraordinary = "IsExtraordinary";
    public static final String  notificationdata = "NotificationData";
    public static final String  notificationdatefor= "NotificationDateFor";
    public static final String  primaryid= "PrimaryId"; 


Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select DateToNotify from " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + 
            " where " + primaryid + " = ? AND  " + notificationfor + " = ?", new String[] { D, selection });
```

It gives me a null in cursor if I pass 1 and 1 as arguments ( The records map to the arguments I pass)

However when I execute the following query, it works perfect:

```
String Tets = "Select DateToNotify from Notifications WHERE PrimaryId = 1 AND NotificationFor =1";
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(Tets, null);
```

**EDIT**

I just tried the following and it works:

```
String Tets = "Select DateToNotify from Notifications WHERE PrimaryId =" +D+ " AND NotificationFor ="+selection;
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(Tets, null);
```

The whole function looks like this:

```
public Cursor alertQueryYYYY(String D, String selection){

    //  Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select DateToNotify from " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + 
    //      " where " + primaryid + " = ? AND  " + notificationfor + " = ?", new String[] { D, selection });

        String Tets = "Select DateToNotify from Notifications WHERE PrimaryId =" +D+ " AND NotificationFor ="+selection;
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(Tets, null); 


        String K = "select DateToNotify from " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + 
                        " where " + primaryid + " = ? AND  " + notificationfor + " = ?"; // new String[] { D, selection })

        System.out.println("Here I am " + K); 
        return c;

    }
```

[This is the image of my table, as I dont have a good image edit software so I uploaded it on another website for clarity reasons.](http://imageshack.com/a/img837/1017/6srv.png)

**EDIT**
The following is the DB creation string and as Pointed out by CL, the error lies in mismatching types.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 ="create table Notifications(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +"NotificationFor Integer," // Weeks/Seconds etc /7 variables
            +"DateToNotify text,"       // Date of Notification
            +"isExtraordinary Integer," // Special notifications, yet unknown
            +"NotificationData Integer," // Weeks/Seconds/ etc / 7 variables
            +"NotificationDateFor text,"
            +"PrimaryId);";
```

Comment: if you have add ones of sqlite manager in firefox  than try your query in that .  when you run your query ther you'll get whats you doing worng .. My be it's related to field_name  those you are using ...

Comment: I checked it in SQLite browser itself, that is why I said that there is no problem with column names or the arguments I pass. Please check the Edit in my question.

Comment: on the Question mark , are you passing the any variable ?

Comment: Yes Two Variables. PrimaryId and NotificationFor. The third query above works just fine for the same arguments. I have grouped them in one single function and to test I comment the query I dont want to run. Just for the sake of checking parameters.

Comment: in the first query change   primaryid ,  notificationfor  to PrimaryId , NotificationFor ...  May be these will creating problem because withot the table ...I am not able to check these query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `1` is not the same as the string `"1"`, so you will not find the record if you search for an ID of the wrong type.

Query parameters are useful to avoid formatting problems and SQL injection attacks.
These problems can occur only with strings, not with plain integers, so to use integer values in your query, you should not use parameters but just insert the values directly:

```
"... WHERE PrimaryId =" +D+ " AND NotificationFor ="+selection;
```

Comment: The "1" in the problem code is intended to be a string because the corresponding column type is a string type. However I might be wrong. Though would be great to know what would be an alternative to passing "1"? String.valueof(1)?

Comment: If it works with `PrimaryId = 1` and not with `PrimaryId = '1'`, then the value in the column is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way to use queries:

```
final SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
 final String[] projection = new String[] {datetonotify };
 final String selection = primaryid + "=? " +notificationfor +"=?";
 final String[] having = new String[] {D,selection};
 Cursor cursor = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, projection, selection, having,
                null, null, null, null);
```

Your code must work to, if there is error, it is not in parameters, but may be in variable DATABASE_TABLE1.